# Gerando um número pseudo-aleatório com base em uma entrada

Tags: algoritmo, números-aleatórios

Preciso gerar um número aleatório baseado em outro número de entrada, de modo que, para o mesmo número de entrada, a função deve sempre gerar o mesmo número de saída.

Por exemplo, `meuRand(4)` sempre retornaria 236 (ou qualquer outro número), e `meuRand(11)` sempre retornaria 1747. Não há problema se por acaso `meuRand(xx)`, com `xx` diferente de 4, também retornasse 236.

Esses valores são só para ilustrar.

Por hora, tenho essa função, que encontrei [aqui](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm), devidamente portada para C, como exemplo:

```
double noise(int x) {
    x = ((x << 13) ^ x);
    x *= x * 15731;
    x += 789221;
    x *= x;
    x += 1376312589;
    x &= 0x7fffffff;
    return 1.0 - ((double)x / 1073741824.0);
}
```

Essa função retorna valores no intervalo de -1 até 1, mas isso não é problema. O retorno ser um número inteiro ou de ponto flutuante é indiferente.

O objetivo final desses números aleatórios é realmente gerar um mapa com um [Perlin Noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) 2D. Por isso gostaria de testar meu algoritmo com outra função de geração de números aleatórios, e preferencialmente, que essa função fosse rápida de ser calculada.

Precisa ser um algoritmo, não pode ser algo como utilizar esse esquema em C, para sempre gerar o mesmo número com base no 4, por exemplo:

```
srand(4);
rand();
```

pois o código final nem sempre será executado em C, C++, C# etc.

Comment: [Pergunta relacionada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9026/215) (não é exatamente uma duplicata, mas algumas respostas lá podem se aplicar aqui)

Comment: Oi mgibsonbr! Valeu, eu tinha visto essa pergunta, mas não a primeira resposta. Acho que dá para fazer um teste :)

Comment: "O retorno ser um número inteiro ou de ponto flutuante é indiferente." Sugeriria trabalhar sempre com inteiros, para não ter problema se mudar de arquitetura de processador (se for desejado que o mapa seja igual em qualquer máquina). Dependendo do tipo de mapa que fizer, uma diferença de arredondamento ou precisão pode te dar um vale numa máquina e uma colina em outra.

Comment: Concordo, @Bacco, isso é perigoso em várias aplicações! Mas nesse caso particular, não! Ainda bem ;)  Dessa vez, basta que o resultado fique "bonito" e está OK!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solução mais simples que posso oferecer é usar simplesmente uma **função de hash** - como o MD5 (ou algo mais sofisticado - embora creio que no seu caso é mais importante que a função seja *rápida*). Elas oferecem o que você busca (mesma saída para a mesma entrada), são amplamente suportadas por diversos sistemas e linguagens de programação, e são consideradas - [em teoria pelo menos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle) (pois servem de base para muitos sistemas criptográficos) - como indistinguíveis na prática de números aleatórios.

E, se o que você quer é uma **sequência** de números aleatórios - não somente um - ainda é possível utilizar o número original como semente de uma sequência, e a partir daí ir incrementando um contador para gerar o número seguinte (ou qualquer outro depois dele). Ex.:

```
aleatorio(semente, indice) = MD5(semente + indice)
```

Outros algoritmos (como alguns propostos numa [pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9026/215)) podem ser ainda mais eficientes, mas se o que se busca é **portabilidade** eu usaria isso como primeira opção.

Comment: Realmente, você sacou algo que esqueci de dizer na pergunta... Seria bom que a função fosse rápida :) Vou testar todas as alternativas.

Comment: Acabei de encontrar outra forma de gerar esse tipo de número aleatório. Depois dá uma olhada na resposta que acabei de colocar aqui, para compartilhar o conhecimento com o pessoal :)

Answer (score 2):

Acabei de encontrar uma forma de gerar esse tipo de número pseudo-aleatório, criada pelo próprio idealizador do *Perlin Noise*, Ken Perlin.

Ele deixou um de seus *talks* disponíveis online [aqui](http://www.noisemachine.com/talk1/). Ao longo da explicação, ele leva para [um de seus outros sites](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/doc/oscar.html), onde mostra o algoritmo original.

Por completude, e pelo fato do algoritmo não ser patenteado/estar disponível online (além de eu já ter feito as devidas referências), vou colocar o [algoritmo](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/doc/oscar.html#noise) dele aqui:

```
/* coherent noise function over 1, 2 or 3 dimensions */
/* (copyright Ken Perlin) */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define B 0x100
#define BM 0xff

#define N 0x1000
#define NP 12   /* 2^N */
#define NM 0xfff

static p[B + B + 2];
static float g3[B + B + 2][3];
static float g2[B + B + 2][2];
static float g1[B + B + 2];
static start = 1;

static void init(void);

#define s_curve(t) ( t * t * (3. - 2. * t) )

#define lerp(t, a, b) ( a + t * (b - a) )

#define setup(i,b0,b1,r0,r1)\
    t = vec[i] + N;\
    b0 = ((int)t) & BM;\
    b1 = (b0+1) & BM;\
    r0 = t - (int)t;\
    r1 = r0 - 1.;

double noise1(double arg)
{
    int bx0, bx1;
    float rx0, rx1, sx, t, u, v, vec[1];

    vec[0] = arg;
    if (start) {
        start = 0;
        init();
    }

    setup(0, bx0,bx1, rx0,rx1);

    sx = s_curve(rx0);

    u = rx0 * g1[ p[ bx0 ] ];
    v = rx1 * g1[ p[ bx1 ] ];

    return lerp(sx, u, v);
}

float noise2(float vec[2])
{
    int bx0, bx1, by0, by1, b00, b10, b01, b11;
    float rx0, rx1, ry0, ry1, *q, sx, sy, a, b, t, u, v;
    register i, j;

    if (start) {
        start = 0;
        init();
    }

    setup(0, bx0,bx1, rx0,rx1);
    setup(1, by0,by1, ry0,ry1);

    i = p[ bx0 ];
    j = p[ bx1 ];

    b00 = p[ i + by0 ];
    b10 = p[ j + by0 ];
    b01 = p[ i + by1 ];
    b11 = p[ j + by1 ];

    sx = s_curve(rx0);
    sy = s_curve(ry0);

#define at2(rx,ry) ( rx * q[0] + ry * q[1] )

    q = g2[ b00 ] ; u = at2(rx0,ry0);
    q = g2[ b10 ] ; v = at2(rx1,ry0);
    a = lerp(sx, u, v);

    q = g2[ b01 ] ; u = at2(rx0,ry1);
    q = g2[ b11 ] ; v = at2(rx1,ry1);
    b = lerp(sx, u, v);

    return lerp(sy, a, b);
}

float noise3(float vec[3])
{
    int bx0, bx1, by0, by1, bz0, bz1, b00, b10, b01, b11;
    float rx0, rx1, ry0, ry1, rz0, rz1, *q, sy, sz, a, b, c, d, t, u, v;
    register i, j;

    if (start) {
        start = 0;
        init();
    }

    setup(0, bx0,bx1, rx0,rx1);
    setup(1, by0,by1, ry0,ry1);
    setup(2, bz0,bz1, rz0,rz1);

    i = p[ bx0 ];
    j = p[ bx1 ];

    b00 = p[ i + by0 ];
    b10 = p[ j + by0 ];
    b01 = p[ i + by1 ];
    b11 = p[ j + by1 ];

    t  = s_curve(rx0);
    sy = s_curve(ry0);
    sz = s_curve(rz0);

#define at3(rx,ry,rz) ( rx * q[0] + ry * q[1] + rz * q[2] )

    q = g3[ b00 + bz0 ] ; u = at3(rx0,ry0,rz0);
    q = g3[ b10 + bz0 ] ; v = at3(rx1,ry0,rz0);
    a = lerp(t, u, v);

    q = g3[ b01 + bz0 ] ; u = at3(rx0,ry1,rz0);
    q = g3[ b11 + bz0 ] ; v = at3(rx1,ry1,rz0);
    b = lerp(t, u, v);

    c = lerp(sy, a, b);

    q = g3[ b00 + bz1 ] ; u = at3(rx0,ry0,rz1);
    q = g3[ b10 + bz1 ] ; v = at3(rx1,ry0,rz1);
    a = lerp(t, u, v);

    q = g3[ b01 + bz1 ] ; u = at3(rx0,ry1,rz1);
    q = g3[ b11 + bz1 ] ; v = at3(rx1,ry1,rz1);
    b = lerp(t, u, v);

    d = lerp(sy, a, b);

    return lerp(sz, c, d);
}

static void normalize2(float v[2])
{
    float s;

    s = sqrt(v[0] * v[0] + v[1] * v[1]);
    v[0] = v[0] / s;
    v[1] = v[1] / s;
}

static void normalize3(float v[3])
{
    float s;

    s = sqrt(v[0] * v[0] + v[1] * v[1] + v[2] * v[2]);
    v[0] = v[0] / s;
    v[1] = v[1] / s;
    v[2] = v[2] / s;
}

static void init(void)
{
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0 ; i < B ; i++) {
        p[i] = i;

        g1[i] = (float)((random() % (B + B)) - B) / B;

        for (j = 0 ; j < 2 ; j++)
            g2[i][j] = (float)((random() % (B + B)) - B) / B;
        normalize2(g2[i]);

        for (j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j++)
            g3[i][j] = (float)((random() % (B + B)) - B) / B;
        normalize3(g3[i]);
    }

    while (--i) {
        k = p[i];
        p[i] = p[j = random() % B];
        p[j] = k;
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < B + 2 ; i++) {
        p[B + i] = p[i];
        g1[B + i] = g1[i];
        for (j = 0 ; j < 2 ; j++)
            g2[B + i][j] = g2[i][j];
        for (j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j++)
            g3[B + i][j] = g3[i][j];
    }
}
```