# Gerador automático de entradas

Tags: c, input-output, input

estou desenvolvendo o algoritmo de cálculo de caminho mínimo de Dijkstra usando a linguagem C, estou fazendo várias soluções para o mesmo problema pra depois testar qual o mais eficiente.

Pra isso eu precisava gerar várias entradas, incluindo entradas gigantescas!
Queria saber se existe um gerador de entradas ou algo do tipo, senão vou ter que escrever na mão um algoritmo pra gerar grafos direcionados e conexos e armazená-los em um txt

Existe algo do tipo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estou assumindo que você busca entradas aleatórias, certo? Nesse artigo da Wikipedia sobre [grafos aleatórios](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grafo_aleat%C3%B3rio) cita-se vários diferentes algoritmos para se gerar um grafo, cada um com propriedades distintas (e complexidade de implementação distinta). Veja em "modelos" na caixa informacional à direita, na Wikipedia em inglês há alguns outros.

Não sei de nenhuma implementação pronta, mas *talvez* você encontre algo desse tipo na biblioteca [LEMON](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon) (parte do projeto [Boost](http://www.boost.org/)) - para C++ entretanto, não C. E de todo modo, você teria que "traduzir" a saída de qualquer ferramenta pronta para o formato que você está usando para representar, então não sei o que daria mais trabalho: usar uma ferramenta pronta, ou implementar você mesmo...

Caso decida implementar você mesmo, o [Modelo Erdõs-Rényi](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi) parece ser o mais simples. Em uma de suas duas variantes:

1. Escolha uma probabilidade `p` entre zero e um (zero: nenhuma aresta; um: grafo totalmente conectado);
2. Crie um grafo com `n` nós;
3. Para cada par de nós `(a,b)`, crie ou não uma aresta entre eles com probabilidade `p`.

Outros modelos produzem grafos com características distintas (ex.: o [Barabási–Albert](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model) gera grafos que se assemelham a "vários sistemas naturais e artificiais, incluindo a internet, redes de citação e em algumas redes sociais."; o [Watts e Strogatz](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_de_Watts_e_Strogatz) gera grafos com  "trajeto médios curtos e alta clustering"; etc). Pense em que tipo de entrada você quer, e veja qual modelo se enquadra mais (i.e. não tente inventar um algoritmo do zero da sua cabeça, pois dificilmente ele sairá do jeito que você quer).

Só mais uma dica: se você estiver usando um [gerador de números pseudo-aleatórios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9026/215) (PRNG) para criar seus grafos, você não precisa salvar o grafo inteiro num txt para reutilizá-lo depois: simplesmente armazene a **semente** do PRNG! Dessa forma, salvando um único número (bem como demais parâmetros de geração, como tamanho do grafo, densidade desejada, etc) você consegue recriar um grafo gigantesco sem precisar armazená-lo todo.

- **Cuidado:** Como apontado por @pmg, é importante que você use uma rotina/biblioteca de PRNG que se mantenha estável frente a atualizações, e não simplesmente usar aquilo que seu ambiente/SO te ofereça a menos que seu algoritmo esteja precisamente especificado. A biblioteca LEMON mencionada anteriormente, por exemplo, possui [sua própria implementação de um PRNG](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/doc/1.2.3/a00266.html), mas a documentação afirma claramente que "essa implementação é especializada para ambas arquiteturas 32-bit e 64-bit. Os geradores diferem ligeiramente na fase de geração e inicialização, de modo que eles produzem duas sequências completamente diferentes".

  Ou seja, se você precisa que seus resultados sejam reprodutíveis em diferentes plataformas e SOs, é importante buscar/implementar um PRNG que não possua essas limitações/que ofereça esse tipo de estabilidade.

Comment: @pmg Obrigado por chamar a atenção a esse detalhe! Resposta atualizada.