# Criar função que retorna números aleatórios em C

Tags: c, algoritmo, random

Estou precisando criar uma função que me retorne números aleatórios sem repetição entre 2 intervalos.

Queria criar um tipo de um jogo de cartas, onde as cartas são embaralhadas, e quando elas retornam nunca saem repetidas.

No meu código está repetindo os valores.

<sup>Código retirado por questões de privacidade</sup>

Comment: Oi Marconi. Por que excluiu a pergunta, mesmo com uma resposta tão completa? Aliás, você já excluiu várias perguntas! Lembre-se de que o conteúdo postado aqui no site não é para usuários específicos, mas sim para toda a internet. Uma resposta que resolve o seu problema pode também resolver o de outras pessoas. Nós moderadores conversamos e decidimos desfazer a exclusão desta pergunta, ok? De agora em diante, por favor pense duas vezes antes de excluir uma postagem. Se quiser discutir o assunto, estamos à disposição. Obrigado.

Comment: @bfavaretto As Perguntas que excluir ou não houveram respostas, ou foram mal planejadas. Peço desculpas. 
Antes de exclui-las irei repensar as perguntas.

Comment: Ok Marconi, obrigado pela compreensão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Função randômica

Imagino que você apenas queira usar uma função assim. [Criar uma não é tarefa muito simples](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9030/101). melhor usar o que já existe pronto.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = rand() %13; //é número de cartas de cada naipe
    printf("Número sorteado %d", r);
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2eUZAf). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/iujgonjy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/Random.c).

A documentação da função `rand()` e `srand()` pode ser [encontrada aqui](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/).

## Algoritmo sem repetição

Acredito que a solução completa que você esteja precisa é baseada no algoritmo [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Algo assim (se acordo com [essa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3348142/221800)):

```
int rand_int(int n) {
    int limit = RAND_MAX - RAND_MAX % n;
    int rnd;

    do {
        rnd = rand();
    } while (rnd >= limit);
    return rnd % n;
}

void shuffle(int *array, int n) {
    int i, j, tmp;

    for (i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = rand_int(i + 1);
        tmp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i];
        array[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Aí agora é adaptar para sua necessidade.

## Baralho

Achei um exemplo mais ou menos pronto para o que você quer [nessa página](http://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=240).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define CARDS 52
#define DRAW 5

void showcard(int card);

int main() {
    int deck[CARDS];
    int c;

/* initialize the deck */
    for (int x = 0; x < CARDS; x++) deck[x] = 0;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (int x = 0; x < DRAW; x++) {
        for(;;) {                 /* loop until a valid card is drawn */
            c = rand() % CARDS;     /* generate random drawn */
            if(deck[c] == 0) {       /* has card been drawn? */
                deck[c] = 1;        /* show that card is drawn */
                showcard(c);        /* display card */
                break;              /* end the loop */
            }
        }                       /* repeat loop until valid card found */
    }
}

void showcard(int card) {
    char *suit[4] = { "Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds" };
    switch (card % 13) {
        case 0:
            printf("%2s","A");
            break;
        case 10:
            printf("%2s","J");
            break;
        case 11:
            printf("%2s","Q");
            break;
        case 12:
            printf("%2s","K");
            break;
        default:
            printf("%2d",card%13+1);
    }
    printf(" of %s\n",suit[card/13]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qb8XYr). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hwbovyti-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/ShuffleCards.c).

Comment: @Marconi [rand + modulus = fail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104478/uniformity-of-random-numbers-taken-modulo-n) => pegue um compilador C++ razoavelmente moderno, facilite sua vida, [use algo politicamente correto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600100/why-are-stdshuffle-methods-being-deprecated-in-c14). Estude.

Comment: @pepper_chico sei muito pouco de C. conheço mais em asp.net C#.

Comment: @Marconi não se preocupe, você está fazendo um exercício de escola e não um sistema para controlar o banco central. Mas nem importa, tem gente que gosta de uma linguagem e fica defendendo ela mesmo que não traga nenhuma vantagem verdadeira.

Comment: @bigown Obrigado.

Comment: @Marconi recomendo altamente que você leia o primeiro link, puro C. O outro é pra facilitar a sua vida somente, você pode implementar distribuição uniforme em C também, ou usar uma lib qualquer com distribuição uniforme de inteiros de forma correta. É bom que você saiba isto, eu mesmo passei bom tempo sem ficar atento pra isto quando é preciso. Um jogo viciado ou criptografia viciada são portas pra hackers. A vantagem [fato] do C++ é que isto já está na lib padrão.

Comment: @Marconi rand + modulo é tão infame quanto a função gets.

Comment: @pepper_chico Ok, muito obrigado.