# Como gerar 10 vezes números aleatórios sem ser repetidos, com loop?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<locale.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<windows.h> 

int main(){

    int nSorteado[6];
    int i, j, n1, n2, op, seq[6];
    int Ncorretos=0, pontos=0, seg;
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    system("color F4");
    
    for(i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("############### JOGO DA MEMÓRIA #################");
        printf("\n*\n* Escolha um intervalo de números: ");
        scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);   
        printf("*\n");
        printf("* Embaralhando os números de %d a %d...\n*", n1, n2);
        
            for(i=0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                nSorteado[i] = n1 + rand() % (n2-n1+1);
            }
        
            printf("\n* Voce tem 5 segundos para decorar os 6 números.\n\n");
            for(i=0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                printf("%d ", nSorteado[i]);
            }
            seg=5;
            do
            {
                printf("\n\n%ds",seg);
                
                if(seg==20)
                {
                    seg=0;
                }
                Sleep(1000);
                seg--;         
            }while(seg>0);
            
            system("cls");
            
            printf("\nQual foi a sequencia dos 5 números sorteados?\n");
            printf("\n*Obs:. Digite os números com espaço entre eles. Ex: 1 2 3 4 5 6.\n\n");
            
            for(i=0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                scanf("%d", &seq[i]);
                if(seq[i] == nSorteado[i])
                {
                    Ncorretos++;
                }
            }
            
            if(Ncorretos == 6)
            {
                printf("Parabéns!! Você acertou!");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Errado! Tente novamente...");
            }
            Sleep(1000);
            system("cls");
        }   
    return 0;
}
```

Obs: Toda vez que o código é executado, ele gera 6 números aleatórios. Na primeira vez que o código é executado e o usuário digita a sequencia correta dos números, ele recebe uma mensagem de "Parabéns", mas nas outras vezes que o usuário digita a sequencia correta, ele recebe uma mensagem de erro. Já tentei de varias formas arrumar mas não deu certo do jogo funcionar normalmente. Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço muito.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/390787/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41829/101

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Gerar números randômicos que não se repetem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136206/gerar-n%c3%bameros-rand%c3%b4micos-que-n%c3%a3o-se-repetem)

Answer (score -3):

Você pode tentar guardar os números aletórios em uma array e sempre que você gerar, utilize um for para verificar se o número aleatorio já foi sorteado.

Comment: Esse tipo de comentário não é resposta para a questão, nesse caso, faça-o como comentário. Só coloque resposta quando a mesma realmente resolver o problema da pergunta em si.

Comment: Agradeço sua resposta. Você poderia dar um exemplo de como guardar os números aleatórios no array e como verifica-los com o for?