# Random() gerando números repetidos

Tags: c#, .net, random

Estou desenvolvendo uma pequena aplicação para realizar importação de XML, a qual faz a busca dos itens presentes na nota e realiza a busca dos mesmos no `DB` interno da empresa. Quando o item não for encontrado, o vínculo é feito manualmente e essa informação é salva numa tabela `ItemFornecXItemEmpresa` para, numa próxima vez, o programa encontrar o item.

Meu problema está na geração do `ObjID`, que é gerado baseado no dia e hora de inserção e mais 5 números randômicos:

```
for (int i = 0; i < itens.Count; i++)
{
    if (itens[i].Novo == true)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        string ano = String.Format("{0:yy}", DateTime.Now);
        string mes = String.Format("{0:MM}", DateTime.Now);
        string dia = String.Format("{0:dd}", DateTime.Now);
        string hora = String.Format("{0:hh}", DateTime.Now);
        string mili = String.Format("{0:ff}", DateTime.Now);
        string random = rand.Next(10000,99999).ToString();

    string id = ano + mes + dia + hora + mili + random;
    [...]
    }
}
```

E toda inserção que faço eu tenho esse tipo de `ID` gerado:

```
150325094512431
1503250946*44723*
1503250947*44723*
150325094929997
150325095062289
1503250951*94581*
1503250952*94581*
201513031638315
201516031131187
201516031136284
201516031137201
```

Observo diversos `ID`s repetidos. Há alguma lógica para isso?

Comment: Creio que seria melhor usar uma coluna com Identity na base de dados (supondo SQL Server), ou UUID, e guardar a data em um local separado. O identificador não é um bom lugar para armazenar data e hora de criação do registro.

Comment: A ideia é gerar números não repetidos usando a data como base na verdade @bfavaretto, e não armazenar propriamente a data. De qualquer forma, não será um aplicativo para distribuição, apenas para testes.

Comment: Entendo. Com a solução do bigown, entendo que os números não irão mais se repetir dentro do loop, mas nada impede que se repitam entre diversas execuções desse bloco de código que você postou (que suponho estar numa função). Mesmo que você criasse uma guarda para isso, cedo ou tarde eles iriam se repetir, já que há uma quantidade não tão grande de números no intervalo que você determinou.

Comment: O número randômico irá se repetir cedo ou tarde, sem dúvidas, é aí que entra a data e a hora pois, quando a `string` *random* repetir, será outro dia (ou ano). Se for no mesmo dia, será em outra hora. Creio que não terei problemas com isso da forma que está (para o meu porte de aplicação, claro). Mas obrigado pela observação.

Comment: Neste caso não seria muito melhor usar sequencial em vez de random? Vai incrementando de um em um, que até dar a volta em 100000 incrementos provavelmente o minuto já mudou.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sim, há. Seu código está inicializando a semente randômica todas as vezes dentro do laço. Então vai repetir mesmo. Se você quer valores diferentes deve iniciar a semente somente uma vez, ou seja, deve retirar a inicialização da variável do laço. Assim (aproveitei pra simplificar):

```
var rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < itens.Count; i++) {
    if (itens[i].Novo) 
        var id = $"{DateTime.Now:yy}{DateTime.Now:MM}{DateTime.Now:dd}{DateTime.Now:hh}{DateTime.Now:ff}{rand.Next(10000, 99999)}";
        [...]
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/SingleSeed.cs).

Tem um detalhes importante, eu acho  melhor guardar o `DateTime.Now` em uma variável e usá-la. Pode ser raro acontecer mas haverá algum caso que que a montagem será inconsistente. Em um caso extremo pode dar uma diferença de um ano. Se a operação começar no último segundo do ano, quase pra virar, então você pode pegar o ano atual na primeira impressão, quando vai pegar o mês já virou, aí ele considera janeiro porque o ano já é outro, só que foi impresso o ano anterior, olha a <strike>cag</strike> besteira que dá. Poderia acontecer com mês, dia, hora, minuto ou até o erro de 1 segundo. E o fato de usar um randômico torna altamente improvável, porém possível dar um conflito, então todo conceito parece errado.

Se deseja que seja único e cronológico talvez deveria usar um tempo mais preciso indo além do segundo, ou fazer sequência tomando o cuidado de ter alguma forma de exclusividade na obtenção do número sequencial. Se deseja só um nome aleatório e não importa a cronologia então deveria usar a API do sistema operacional ou de uma biblioteca padrão que fornece um nome garantidamente único.

Para entender melhor e ver exemplos de uso leia com atenção toda documentação do [`Random()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Veja um exemplo demonstrando o problema:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            WriteLine(rand.Next(10000,99999));
        }
        WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            rand = new Random();
            WriteLine(rand.Next(10000,99999));
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/upTAJU). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4fA7tT). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/RandomRange.cs).

Comment: Caramba, impressionante isso para mim. Há algum motivo para essa repetição? Digo, iniciar uma nova instancia de Random() a cada `loop` pode não ser correto, mas deveria gerar números diferentes, não?

Comment: @CassioMilanelo depende. `Random()` utiliza uma semente temporal `Environment.TickCount`. Se forem criadas varias instâncias em rápida sucessão, a semente acaba por ser a mesma (devido a precisão do `TickCount`).

Comment: Não. Esta é a característica dele, o computador não consegue gerar números de fato randômicos. Tem maneiras de ajudar nisto. Daria para manter sua lógica e obter números diferentes mas o mais correto em termo de lógica é esta. Esta função deve gerar sequências de números que podem ser reproduzidos. Para entender um pouco mais sobre o assunto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9026/101