# O que é Mersenne Twister?

Tags: números-aleatórios

O PHP possui uma função chamada `rand`. Também existe uma função chamada `mt_rand`.

Estava estudando sobre essas funções e percebi que, em versões anteriores, era necessário de utilizar um tal de "semeador de números aleatórios".

Um deles é a função chamada `mt_srand`.

Nesse trecho do [Manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mt-srand.php) vi que existe uma referência ao nome `Mersenne Twister`. Percebi então que esse `mt_` no início da função tinha algo relacionado.

Cheguei a ver no Wikipédia alguma coisa, mas achei um pouco vago.

Então gostaria de matar essa curiosidade:

- O que é Mersenne Twister? Tem alguma coisa haver com esse semeador ou o processo de randomificação?

Comment: Relacionado: [Como é gerada a randomização pelo computador?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9026/91)

Comment: Relacionada também @rray: [O que é uma semene aleatória?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104335/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-semente-aleat%C3%B3ria)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Traduzo artigo da Wikipédia a respeito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister):

> O Mersenne-Twister é um pseudogerador de números aleatórios (PRNG). É de longe o pseudogerador de uso geral mais usado. Seu nome deriva do fato que seu intervalo é um número [Primo de Mersenne](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primo_de_Mersenne).
>
> Foi desenvolvido em 1997 por Makoto Matsumoto (松本 眞?) e Takuji Nishimura (西村 拓士?). Foi desenvolvido especificamente para retificar velhos problemas encontrados pseudogeradores mais antigos. Foi o primeiro pseudogerador a prover geração rápida de números inteiros pseudoaleatórios com qualidade.
>
> A versão mais comum do algoritmo utilizada é baseada no Primo de Marsenne 219937−1. A implementação padrão dele, MT19937, usa uma palavra inteira de 32 bits. Existe uma outra implementação que usa uma palavra de 64 bits, MT19937-64, e que gera uma sequência bem diferente.