# O que é uma semente aleatória?

Tags: números-aleatórios

Fiz uma pergunta aqui a respeito de uma dúvida que tive em relação à termos utilizados em geração de números aleatórios.

[O que é Mersenne Twister?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104329/o-que-%C3%A9-mersenne-twister/104333#104333)

Lá eu cito que o PHP usa um termo chamado "semear números aleatórios" ou "semente aleatória".

Essa é uma referência à funções `mt_srand` e `srand` que, segundo o Manual do PHP, anteriormente às versões `4.1` era obrigatória a utilização dessas funções antes de invocar funções que geravam números aleatórios (`mt_rand` e `rand`).

E tenho a impressão de já ter visto essas funções "semeadoras" em `C`.

O que é uma semente aleatória?

Por que, anteriormente à essas versões, era necessário chamar um semeador, e agora não é mais?

Comment: Bem, eu queria saber por que essas funções não são mais chamadas para utilizar os "aleatórios" também.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resposta rápida: porque alteraram o algoritmo para o *Mersenne Twister*.

---

Uma semente aleatória é qualquer número ou vector usado para inicializar um gerador de números pseudo-aleatórios que, por sua vez, é um algoritmo determinístico para gerar números cujas sequências são aproximadamente as que se iriam esperar de números (verdadeiramente, enfatize-se) aleatórios. A importância de se gerar bons números aleatórios tem a ver com as suas inúmeras aplicações, desde a criptografia até à simulação computacional.

Nas versões 4 e 5 do PHP existe uma função (`mt_rnd`) para substituir a utilização do gerador de números pseudo-aleatórios das `libc` antigas com `rand` porque os algoritmos anteriores eram mais lentos e havia suspeitas de terem características pouco desejáveis para calcular bons números aleatórios. A nova versão utiliza, de facto, o *Mersenne Twister* que é o algoritmo mais comum em todo o mundo para gerar este tipo de números (pelo menos no que concerne as aplicações mais comuns).