# O que é e para que serve um Seeder?

Tags: terminologia, migrations

Vi no `Laravel` que existe uma pasta chamada `database`. Nela temos os migrations e o seeds.

Eu entendo que as migrations são migrações, são códigos que fornecem especificações para criação das tabelas no banco de dados, sem a necessidade de  conhecer o SGDB que se pretende utilizar.

Porém o que seria esse `seeder` ou `seed`?

Esse nome Seeder é algum conceito da programação, ou algo relacionado com banco de dados?

Está relacionado diretamente com as migrações (migrations)?

**Nota**: Lembrando que a pergunta não é sobre Laravel, mas sim sobre a explanação sobre o nome Seeder ou Seed que aparece lá.

Comment: Não sei se tem a ver, mas talvez tenha [Como é gerada a randomização pelo computador?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9030/14213).

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert acho que o nome tem sentido, mas o objetivo da pergunta não. Seed tá relacionado a "semear" e Seeder "semeador". No Laravel eu vi que o Seeder serve para inserir dados no banco, mas não poderia fazer isso no Migration? Por isso a confusão!

Comment: Seeder é o cara que tem o arquivo completo na máquina :P >> torrents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Porém o que seria esse seeder ou seed?**

Nada mais é do que dados pré determinados que serão inseridos no banco de dados na inicialização do mesmo.

**Está relacionado diretamente com as migrações (migrations)?**

Não com migrations em si, mas sim no conceito de "Code First", ou seja, onde você cria seu banco de dados de acordo com o modelo que você de dados que sua aplicação possui.

**E quando devo utilizar?**

Esse conceito é muito utilizado em testes, mas não se limitam somente à testes. Um bom exemplo é quando você necessita criar um usuário sempre que for "instalar" seu sistema em um novo ambiente. Ao invés de criar um usuário na mão, pode configurar um **seed** do usuário e senha que será inserido automaticamente no sistema, simples não?
Outro exemplo seria os dados em tabelas que irão preencher `combobox`, cidades/estados, dentre muitos outros exemplos.

**Fungindo um pouco do foco...**

Você comentou sobre larável, mas irei colocar um exemplo com o **Entity Framework** aqui.

```
public class SchoolDBInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SchoolDBContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(SchoolDBContext context)
    {
        var user = new User{Name = "Admin", Password = "Admin"};
        context.Users.Add(user );
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Neste exemplo, toda vez que o banco for inicializado pelo código, será inserido o usuário Admin na base de dados.

Comment: Apesar de ser `EF` o exemplo, deu para entender perfeitamente. Estou treinando muito `C#`, mestres +1

Answer (score 2):

Seed é o conceito de "alimentar" sua aplicação com dados de teste. Em Laravel, classes Seeders são responsáveis por inserir os dados de teste na sua aplicação.

Comment: Gabriel, apenas para ajudar, os Seeders não são somente para testes, pode ser usado em produção também.

Comment: Obrigado Wallace pelo adendo.