# O que é seeder e migration?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia

Quando se trata de atualização de banco de dados em um projeto, sempre percebo o termo *Migrations* sendo usado para manter a atualização do banco entre os envolvidos em um determinado projeto.

Também já me deparei com o termo *seed* ou *seeder* quando se trata de inserção de dados para teste.

Eu tenho pouco conhecimento sobre tais termos, e gostaria de me aprofundar.

- O que é uma *migration*?
- O que é um *seeder*?
- *Seeder* e *Migration* podem fazer a mesma coisa, ou são sempre coisas diferentes?

Comment: Relacionada: [O que é e para que serve um Seeder?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126770/91)

Comment: @rray bem lembrado, eu estava procurando isso.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> O que é uma *migration*?

Neste contexto específico, *migration* é a definição que se dá ao gerenciamento de mudanças incrementais e reversíveis em esquemas (estrutura) de banco de dados. Isso permite que seja possível ter um controle "das versões" do banco de dados.

As *migrations* são executadas sempre que for necessário atualizar a estrutura do banco ou reverter as alterações para uma *migration* antiga.

Não necessariamente cada *migration* é uma atualização no banco de dados, a forma mais comum é uma atualização fazer uso de várias *migrations*.

É algo muito usado no desenvolvimento de software ágil, onde geralmente o desenvolvimento da aplicação é feito em conjunto com um banco de dados que está em construção. Assim, a estrutura da base de dados vai sendo alterada em conjunto com o desenvolvimento.

> O que é um *seeder*?

Como o próprio nome diz, um *seeder* é um semeador. Neste contexto específico serve para alimentar a base de dados com dados.

Geralmente é usado para popular a base com dados padrões, necessários pro funcionamento correto da aplicação.

Por exemplo: você desenvolve uma aplicação que só pode ser acessada por usuários autenticados, quando esta publicação for publicada pela primeira vez, a estrutura do banco de dados vai ser criada. Como será possível acessar a aplicação para criar o primeiro usuário? Bem, existem várias maneiras de se lidar com isso, o *seeder* é uma delas (ótima maneira, na minha opinião. Diga-se passagem).

> *Seeder* e *migration* podem fazer a mesma coisa, ou são sempre coisas diferentes?

Embora relacionadas, elas não tem nada a ver. *Seeder* faz uma coisa, *migration* faz outra.

Dependendo da ferramenta/*framework* que estiver usando, uma migration específica pode conter um *seeder* específico, mas tenha em mente que a *migration* atualiza a estrutura da base de dados, enquanto o *seeder* serve para popular a base.

Comment: Muito boa a explicação. Melhor impossível +1