# Adicionar coluna em uma tabela já utilizada por um programa, poderia prejudicar o funcionamento do mesmo?

Tags: postgresql, tabela-html

Possuo um banco de dados PostgreSQL que é utilizado para uma aplicação desenvolvida em **Delphi**, porém agora terei que usar esse mesmo banco para uma nova aplicação que será desenvolvida em **Java**, preciso de algumas colunas que ainda não existem em algumas tabelas já utilizadas, minha dúvida é se eu adicionar uma coluna a uma tabela já existente e que já é utilizada isso poderia prejudicar o programa que já esta sendo executado em cima dessa tabela?

Comment: Migração serve para mitigar esses possíveis problemas. Veja as respostas de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207501/64969, pode ajudar a esclarecer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você só tem que se preocupar com as condições do mesmo, por exemplo, se você colocar essas novas colunas e colocar elas como "NOT NULL" em um "INSERT" do aplicativo Delphi ai vai dar problema.

Mas ai é só você dar valores default, outro exemplo. Se a coluna não pode ser vazia, coloque que quando não receber os dados, o valor assumirá 0.

Comment: No caso essa coluna não será `NOT NULL` pois será um campo adicional não obrigatório

Comment: Então manda vê tio Vader

Comment: rs valeu pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Olá, R. Santos!

É uma questão bastante relativa.
Depende de como o código fonte do software foi feito, por exemplo: Caso eu possua algum `SELECT * FROM...` a sua nova coluna irá aparecer nos resultados, isso pode complicar caso essa coluna tenha um destino diferente como definir se algo está ativo ou não, etc. Caso contrário, não vejo problemas...