# Como a semente influencia na geração de números aleatórios?

Tags: .net, algoritmo, números-aleatórios

A dúvida é bem simples, gostaria de saber como a classe `System.Random` gera números pseudoaleatoriedade aleatórios a partir duma semente, o que acho pouco estranho. Eu sei que eles **não são totalmente aleatórios, e por isso tenho minha dúvida de como são realmente gerados.** Por exemplo,

```
int x = new Random(123).Next(1, 100);
```

`x` terá um valor aleatório, mas se eu sempre usar essa semente, não será mais aleatório e portanto, essa semente irá sempre retornar o mesmo valor nos métodos `Next`, `NextDouble` e `NextBytes`?

Se sim, como é o algoritmo de criação desses números aleatórios com base nesta semente?

**Atualização**

> O centro da minha pergunta é **como é gerado o número aleatório com base na semente**, e não como **é gerado esse número aleatório**. O centro da questão foi perguntar **no que e como a semente influência na geração deste número.**

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como é gerada a randomização pelo computador?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9026/como-%c3%a9-gerada-a-randomiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-pelo-computador)

Comment: @Bacco pergunta atualizada para ser o mais clara possível.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx):
*Os números pseudo-aleatórios são escolhidos com igual probabilidade a partir de um conjunto finito de números. Os números escolhidos não são completamente aleatórios porque um algoritmo matemático é usado para selecioná-los, mas são suficientemente aleatórios para fins práticos. A implementação atual da classe Random é baseada em uma versão modificada do algoritmo de gerador de números aleatórios subtrativos de Donald E. Knuth. Para mais informações, ver D. E. Knuth. A Arte da Programação de Computadores, Volume 2: Algoritmos Seminuméricos. Para gerar um número aleatório criptograficamente seguro, como aquele que é adequado para criar uma senha aleatória, use a classe RNGCryptoServiceProvider ou derivar uma classe de System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.*

Basicamente, essa classe gera números aleatórios usando como "base" um outro valor, que seria o número de milissegundos que se passaram desde que o sistema operacional foi iniciado (Environment.TickCount). Esse é o padrão, caso você não passe nenhum valor no construtor.

Se você passar um número conhecido, aí sim os valores serão sempre os mesmo.

Exemplo:

```
var r = new Random(10);
Console.WriteLine(r.Next(1, 100)); //irá sempre retornar 95
Console.WriteLine(r.Next(1, 100)); //irá sempre retornar 75

r = new Random();
Console.WriteLine(r.Next(1, 100)); //retorno aleatório
Console.WriteLine(r.Next(1, 100)); //retorno aleatório
```

Fonte: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs

Comment: Então esse algoritmo para criação de números aleatórios é usado em todos sistemas? Por exemplo, se eu pedir um número aleatório com tal semente em **PHP**, o valor retornado será o mesmo se fizer o mesmo procedimento em **C#**?

Comment: Não sei dizer onde mais ele é usado. Vale lembrar que a classe Random implementa uma versão modificado do algoritmo. Mas obviamente, se a mesma implementação for usada em outras linguagens, o mesmo valor será retornado sim.