# Gerar caracteres aleatórios com a classe Random

Tags: java, random, char

Foi me passado o seguinte código para servir de auxílio na resolução de um exercício.

```
Random gerador = new Random();
gerador.setSeed(4);
System.out.println((char)(’a’ + (Math.abs(gerador.nextInt()) % 26)));
```

Criei uma classe para testar o código:

```
public class Random {

    private static final Random gerador = new Random();  

    public static void main (String[] args){

        gerador.setSeed(4);    
        System.out.println((char)('a' + Math.abs(gerador.nextInt() % 26)));

    }//fim do main

}//fim da classe
```

**1 -** Tem sido retornado o seguinte erro quando tento compilar:

```
Random.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    gerador.setSeed(4);
           ^
  symbol:   method setSeed(int)
  location: variable gerador of type Random
Random.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println((char)('a' + Math.abs(gerador.nextInt() % 26)));
                                                    ^
  symbol:   method nextInt()
  location: variable gerador of type Random
2 errors
```

**2 -** Além do erro, eu não entendi o que faz o `.setSeed`

Quanto a parte do código:

```
(char)('a' + Math.abs(gerador.nextInt() % 26))
```

Eu entendo que o `Math.abs()` vai pegar o valor absoluto do resto da divisão inteira de um numero aleatório dividido por 26.

**3-** Mas por que esse valor está sendo concatenado com: `'a'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código está usando a classe [`java.util.Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), que é uma classe nativa do Java para geração de números aleatórios.

O problema é que você criou uma classe com o mesmo nome (`Random`), e aí o compilador tenta procurar os métodos `setSeed` e `nextInt` na sua classe. E como esses métodos não existem, dá o erro de compilação.

Então a primeira coisa a fazer é mudar o nome da sua classe para qualquer coisa que não seja `Random`. E não se esqueça de fazer o `import` da classe `java.util.Random` também:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class TestRandom { // mude o nome da classe para outro que não seja Random

    private static final Random gerador = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // agora tudo compila
        gerador.setSeed(4);
        System.out.println((char) ('a' + Math.abs(gerador.nextInt() % 26)));
    }
}
```

---

Quanto ao método [`setSeed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#setSeed-long-), bem, ele muda o *seed* do objeto `Random`.
De forma resumida, os números gerados por esta classe não são puramente aleatórios. Na verdade eles são [pseudo-aleatórios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9026/112052), pois o que acontece internamente são vários cálculos que geram números que *parecem* aleatórios.

E todos esses cálculos partem de um valor inicial, chamado de *seed*. Se dois objetos `Random` são criados com o mesmo *seed*, eles irão gerar a mesma sequência. Veja a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) para mais detalhes.

Dito isso, usar `setSeed` e passar sempre o mesmo valor, como você fez, vai resultar no mesmo número sendo gerado todas as vezes que este código for executado.

Se quer que o resultado seja mais aleatório e não seja o mesmo a cada execução, não precisa usar `setSeed`. Quando você cria um novo objeto `Random` (com `new Random()`), ele já é inicializado com um *seed* que, [segundo a documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random--), é "*muito provável que seja diferente de qualquer outra invocação deste construtor*".

---

Quanto à sua última dúvida, o número resultante da expressão `Math.abs(...)` não está sendo concatenado ao `char`, e sim somado.

Isso acontece porque um `char` - de maneira resumida - também pode ser tratado como um número. Ex:

```
char c = 'a';
System.out.println((int) c); // 97
```

Ao fazer o *cast* para `int`, é impresso `97`, que é o valor do [*codepoint* correspondente ao caractere `a`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0061/index.htm) (neste link o valor do *codepoint* é `U+0061`, já que o Unicode usa os valores em hexadecimal - para entender melhor como funcionam os *codepoints* do Unicode, sugiro a leitura [deste artigo](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) e [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052)).

Também é possível passar um valor numérico diretamente, fazendo o *cast* para `char`, e o resultado é o caractere cujo *codepoint* tem esse valor numérico. Ex:

```
char c = (char) 39321;
System.out.println(c); // 香
```

Neste caso, o `char` terá o caractere que corresponde ao *codepoint* 39321 (no caso, é o [caractere `香`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/9999/index.htm) - e veja novamente neste link que o valor está em hexadecimal: `U+9999`).

E como um `char` pode ser manipulado como número, também podemos somar um valor ao mesmo:

```
char c = 'a' + 1;
System.out.println((int) c); // 98
System.out.println(c); // b
```

Este código imprime:

```
98
b
```

Ou seja, ao somar `1` ao caractere `a`, o resultado é o *codepoint* correspondente ao `a` (que já vimos que é 97) somado ao número 1, que dá 98. Então o `char` passa a ser o caractere correspondente ao *codepoint* 98, que é a letra `b`.

---

Então o que seu código faz é obter uma letra entre `a` e `z`, já que o resultado de `% 26` sempre retorna um número entre 0 e 25 (quando for zero, o resultado será o próprio `a`, e quando for 25, será `z`). Isso só é possível porque os *codepoints* destes caracteres são sequenciais: o *codepoint* da letra `b` é exatamente 1 acima do `a`, o `c` é 1 acima do `b`, etc. [Veja este link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/basic_latin/list.htm) para mais detalhes.

---

Outra opção para fazer a mesma coisa é [passar um parâmetro para `nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-), indicando o valor máximo que pode ser retornado:

```
System.out.println((char) ('a' + gerador.nextInt(26)));
```

Com `nextInt(26)`, o resultado é um número inteiro entre zero e 25. Isso elimina a necessidade de usar `% 26` e `Math.abs`.