# Como usar random.seed() em Python?

Tags: python, random

Preciso gerar um número aleatório utilizando a linguagem Python, na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed) vi que existe uma função `random.seed()` para aumentar a aleatoriedade do número gerado, mas achei bem confusa a descrição dessa função.

Alguém pode explicar melhor como devo usá-la para aumentar a aleatoriedade? Uso em conjunto com o módulo `datetime`? Devo usar toda vez antes de executar `random.random()` ou chamá-la uma vez basta?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como é gerada a randomização pelo computador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9026/como-%c3%a9-gerada-a-randomiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-pelo-computador)

Comment: A dúvida é preciso usar sempre random.seed() antes de chamar random.random() ou não? A função Python random.random() da biblioteca já gera um seed internamente?

Comment: Random já gera um seed, você pode definir um seed manualmente, isso é útil para testar alguns procedimentos, pois você já conhecendo os números gerados consegue prever o comportamento e "debugar" corretamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para aumentar a aleatoriedade, faça uso de [`random.SystemRandom()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom):

Acontece o seguinte: a parte mais visitada da documentação oficial mostra "chamáveis" que parecem funções, no módulo `random` - fazemos

```
import random

a = random.randint(...)
b = random.choice(...)
```

Mas essas "funções" na verdade são métodos de uma classe 
`random.Random` que são expostos direto no módulo pra facilidade de uso.

Então, se você cria uma instância de `random.Random` - vai ter como métodos essas mesmas chamadas - randint, randrange, choice, etc... 
e um `seed`. Só que o módulo `random` tem também a classe especializada
`SystemRandom` que usa como *fonte* dos números aleatórios a API do sistema operacional para isso.  Ou seja, no Linux pega valores de `/dev/random`, no Windows usa `CryptGenRandom`, etc...Esses números aleatórios do sistema são, na medida do possível, garantidamente aleatórios o suficiente para uso em tarefas de criptografia, etc... e muito além dos pseudo-aleatórios que o `random.Random` normal fornece.

Então, é só criar uma instância de `SystemRandom` e chamar os métodos dessa instância, em vez das funções normais do módulo random:

```py
from random import SystemRandom

random = SystemRandom ()

a = random.randint(...)
b = random.choice(...)
```

Quanto ao  `seed`, em objetos `SystemRandom` a função `seed` existe, por força do modelo de orientação a objetos, em que classes especializadas tem que expor os métodos e atributos dos pais, mas na verdade, ele não é usado - está até na documentação dele: `Stub method.  Not used for a system random number generator.`

A fonte de dados aleatórios usada pelo `SystemRandom` fica exposta no módulo `os` e pode ser usada diretamente também com a chamada `os.urandom(n)` - e devolve uma sequência de bytes com os valores fornecidos pelo sistema operacional. O `SystemRandom` encapsula essa chamada e já disponibiliza todos os métodos práticos que conhecemos - randint, choice, uniform, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Ola, o python ele não gera um numero aleatório, eles são pseudo-aleatórios ou seja determinísticos. Ele é gerado apartir do numero que você coloca na `random.seed()`!
Veja um exemplo que fiz.

```html
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#Meu Décimo quinto Programa
#Trabalhando com numerosAleatorios

#importar a biblioteca
import random

#Uma seed(semente) de numero 10.

random.seed(10)
#gera 10 numeros aleatórios
for i in range(10):
#Escolhe um numero aleatório entre 0 e 999
    numero = random.randint(0,1000)
    print(numero)
```

Ao executar esse código multiplas vezes você não obtem resultados diferentes para este intervalo de range (gerei 10 numeros) pois a seed fica viciada e sempre gera os mesmo numeros. por isto é interessante colocar um valor aleatório como parametro para a seed