# Consistência nos resultados em Python

Tags: python, random, numpy

Olá, estou estudando código em python e me deparei com esta linha:

```
np.random.seed(0)
```

no qual diz para consistência de resultados. Eu pesquisei, mas ainda não consegui compreender a função desse comando. Alguém poderia explicar ou indicar o local onde posso encontrar documentação?

Valeu ajuda.

Comment: O método `seed()` serve para iniciar o gerador de números pseudoaleatórios. Documentação: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como é gerada a randomização pelo computador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9026/como-%c3%a9-gerada-a-randomiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-pelo-computador)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.random.seed(0)` define que a geração randômica de números seguirá um padrão pré definido.

Ao fazer `np.random.seed(0)`, a próxima chamada de `numpy.random.rand(n)`, sendo `n` o tamanho do vetor a ser gerado, seguirá um padrão fixo.

Por exemplo, sem definir uma seed, chamadas iguais de `numpy.random.rand(n)` retornariam resultados diferentes.

```
>>> numpy.random.rand(5)
array([0.79172504, 0.52889492, 0.56804456, 0.92559664, 0.07103606])
>>> numpy.random.rand(5)
array([0.64589411, 0.43758721, 0.891773  , 0.96366276, 0.38344152])
```

Porém ao setar a seed antes de chamar `numpy.random.rand(n)`, você garante que a sequência gerada será igual / seguirá o mesmo padrão todas as vezes.

```
>>> numpy.random.seed(0)
>>> numpy.random.rand(5)
array([0.5488135 , 0.71518937, 0.60276338, 0.54488318, 0.4236548 ])
>>> numpy.random.seed(0)
>>> numpy.random.rand(5)
array([0.5488135 , 0.71518937, 0.60276338, 0.54488318, 0.4236548 ])
```

Note que ao chamar `numpy.random.rand(5)`, a seed é resetada, sendo necessário seta-la novamento com `numpy.random.seed(0)`.