# Escolher entre dois números em Java

Tags: java, random

Eu estou a construir um jogo em que quero que, num terreno, um objeto com dadas coordenadas no terreno se espalhe, criando mais *pixels* de si próprio no terreno.
Cada *pixel* desses seria representado pelo número 4.

Aqui vai o código:

```
public void interact(mainclass a) {
    a.terrain[x][y] = 4;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int directionX = escolher(-1, 1);
    int directionY = escolher(-1, 1);
    a.terrain[x + directionX][y + directionY] = 4;
}
```

Na classe `mainclass`, eu tenho as informações do terreno, bem como o terreno em si, na forma de `int[][]`.

A direção em que o dado objeto se espalha é aleatória. O problema é que, para a função escolher, eu tentei utilizar o `Random rand` para gerar um número aleatório entre -1 e 1, o problema é que continua lá o 0, entre -1 e 1.

A função `escolher` não existe, apenas escrevi para dar um exemplo.

Ou seja, não posso utilizar o `Random`. Tenho de arranjar uma forma de escolher literalmente entre ambos os números (-1 e 1).

Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É claro que você pode usar `Random`. Se só existem dois valores possíveis para escolher, uma opção seria:

```
public static Random rand = new Random();

public int escolher() {
    int n = rand.nextInt(2);
    return n == 1 ? n : -1;
}

...
int directionX = escolher();
```

[`rand.nextInt(2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) retorna um número aleatório (na verdade [pseudo-aleatório](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9026/112052)) entre zero (inclusive) e 2 (exclusive). Ou seja, ele só retorna zero ou um.

Então se o número for 1, retorno ele mesmo. Senão, eu retorno -1.

Além disso, não precisa criar um `Random` novo cada vez que o método for chamado, pode criar um só apenas uma vez, fora do método.

---

Se quer que o método receba todos os valores possíveis, basta modificá-lo um pouco:

```
public int escolher(int... valores) {
    int n = rand.nextInt(valores.length);
    return valores[n];
}

// escolhe -1 ou 1
int directionX = escolher(-1, 1);

// escolhe 1, 2, 5 ou 90
int directionX = escolher(1, 2, 5, 90);
```

Usei a sintaxe de [varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/766559), assim você pode passar quantos valores forem necessários.

---

O único porém é que se você não passar nenhum número (ou seja, chamar apenas `escolher()`) dará erro, pois nesse caso `valores.length` será zero e `nextInt` deve receber um número maior que zero (caso contrário, ele lança exceção).

Passar apenas um número também é meio inútil (`escolher(x)` sempre retornará o `x`, independente do valor que `x` tiver), então você pode incluir uma validação e lançar uma exceção caso o método receba menos que dois valores:

```
public int escolher(int... valores) {
    if (valores.length < 2)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Você deve passar pelo menos 2 valores");
    int n = rand.nextInt(valores.length);
    return valores[n];
}

// escolhe -1 ou 1
int directionX = escolher(-1, 1);

// as duas chamadas abaixo lançam exceção
int directionX = escolher(-1);
int directionX = escolher();
```

---

O problema é que este tipo de erro (passar menos parâmetros que o permitido) só será detectado em tempo de execução. Outra forma de resolver é forçar que tenha pelo menos dois parâmetros, assim se forem passados menos, o programa nem compila:

```java
public int escolher(int v1, int v2, int... restante) {
    int n = rand.nextInt(restante.length + 2);
    if (n == 0)
        return v1;
    if (n == 1)
        return v2;
    return restante[n - 2];
}

// com 2 ou mais parâmetros, continua funcionando como as soluções anteriores
int directionX = escolher(-1, 1);
int directionX = escolher(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

// mas com menos de 2 parâmetros, ***nem sequer compila***
int directionX = escolher(1);
int directionX = escolher();
```

Comment: Obrigado. Era mesmo disto que eu estava a precisar.